# Is the black hole surface area actually zero?

Tags: black-holes, entropy, event-horizon

From quantum mechanics we know that entropy of a part can be smaller than the entropy of the whole.

I wonder whether a similar rule works for GR as well.

Quantum mechanics predicts that the entropy of the whole universe is zero.

At the same time we know that all astronomical objects put far enough take greater solid angle than a similar object near us. Far enough objects even in opposite directions have smaller distance between them than from them to us. For example, a tennis ball put sufficiently close to the cosmic horizon will span over sufficient part of the sky. This ultimately means that we are surrounded by a point-like singularity. And entropy of such singularity (proportional to the area) is zero.

A similar consideration is true for a black hole. Any object approaching it will cover the greater share of the surface as it approaches. Even a planck-scale partile will cover the whole BH surface when approaching close enough.

This may mean that the true area of the horizon is actually zero, with finite area being only an illusion appearing in the flat coordinates.

This gives total entropy of a black hole to be zero which is in accordance with the fact that all of the BH information is located outside the horizon (to avoid the information paradox). If we subtract from the horizon's area(as seen by an observer at infinity) the total entropy of objects visible outside the horizon, we will arrive at zero.

Similarly if we subtract from the supposed mass of the BH the total mass of matter visible outside the horizon, we also will arrive at zero: all mass of the BH is in the matter immediately surrounding the horizon.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand your comment about entropy and area... entropy basically represents the _number of physical states_ of a system. It doesn't matter if the system you're observing "looks" small... it has the same number of states over there at the cosmic horizon as it does over here.

Comment: @chase entropy of a system bounded by a horizon is proportional to the horizon's area. It is a well known result.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your terminology... cosmic horizon = CMB? Or are you referring to the BH's event horizon, or some combination? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @chase no. I am referring to the cosmic event horizon for a case of static universe and to the cosmic particle horizon for a case of universe started from Big Bang (that is ours).My argument is that the true area of these boundaries is zero bуcause a ruler approaching them from our perspective will expand and cover the whole surface perimeter.

Comment: Where can I read up on the idea that a ruler will expand to cover the horizon? It seems obviously not true in the case of a Rindler horizon, which makes me suspicious. I've heard about "information" spreading over the horizon according to string theory, but not classical objects. Can you point me to a resource?